# How to make second dropdown greater than first dropdown Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

I am using Laravel 7 and PHP 7.4. I have a long form into my website. I have 2 dropdowns. Both dropdowns are supposed to show the list of years say **"1920 - 2020"**

My first dropdown is populating list of years from database using ajax. Now here the logic comes in play. I need my second dropdown should display the list of years greater than the year selected for first dropdown.

For example, in first dropdown, if the user selects the year **1950**, the second dropdown should start from **1951-2020**.

I' m wondering how can I do that in Laravel?

Blade

```
<div class="form-group">
      <select id="first_dropdown" data-dependent="second-dropdown">
           <option value="">1920</option>
           <option value="">1921</option>
           <option value="">1922</option>
           ...................
       </select>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
      <select id="second_dropdown" >
           <option selected value=""></option>
       </select>
```

Controller

```
public function fetchYear(Request $request)
{

    $get_model_id = $request->get('model_id');
    $model_dependent = $request->get('model_dependent');

    $fetch_year = DB::table('my-database')
        ->select('year')
        ->distinct()
        ->where('model_id', '=', $get_model_id)
        ->where(function ($query) {
            $query->orWhere('is_active', '=', '1');
        })
        ->orderBy('year', 'ASC')
        ->get();

    $show_year = '<option value="">Select ' . ucfirst($model_dependent) . '</option>';
    foreach ($fetch_year as $row) {
        $show_year .= '<option value="' . $row->year . '">' . $row->year . '</option>';
    }
    echo $show_year;
}
```

Comment: "if the user selects the year 1950, the second dropdown should start from 1951-2020."...for that you need Javascript, to detect the "change" event on the first dropdown, and then change the contents of the second one accordingly. You can't do it from PHP (or at least, not without a cumbersome full postback of the page, which is slow and not at all user-friendly).

Comment: P.S. `<option selected` ...why have you got _all_ of them as `selected` in your HTML? You can't have every value selected. At most one can be selected (unless you're using a `multiple` select to choose many values, but it sounds like you don't want that).

Comment: @ADyson 
I see. How can I do that ?

Comment: Just the way I said. Handle the "change" event on the dropdown, get the value that was selected, and then replace all the options in the second dropdown with a new set which contain the required range of values. (N.B. These are all simple JavaScript operations which you can easily research for yourself, and then make an attempt at solving. if you're not very familiar with JavaScript, it would be a good learning exercise. If you get stuck, show your JS code and explain where you're having trouble.)

Comment: What you're asking for is very similar to a common concept which is generally called "cascading dropdowns" - where the content of a second dropdown depends on the value selected in the first one. Knowing that terminology might help you with your searches.

Comment: @ADyson
Let me find out the script.